# Information about SSL and apache

Tags: php, apache, ssl, https

Every now and then and since the last week more often I get questions about HTTPS & SSL. So no I wanted to get more into it and looking for some good information about the subject.

Furthermore, I have develop on XAMPP and VISTA and I am looking for a good tutorial to get SSL working on this environment.

Has anyone got good resources or tutorials or books about this subject? 
Or a good tutorial on how to get it working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) and [this](http://www.apache-ssl.org/) should get you going in the right direction. As for setting up XAMPP to use SSL, I don't think that's really necessary, since XAMPP is designed for local development, not a production server, so it won't do you any good to add SSL to something that won't be carrying any important information.

Answer (score 0):

Dont go head first into the HowTos! Be sure to read some background on HTTPS and SSL to get a understanding of more specifically what kind of security problems it adresses.

Words like "SSL", "certificates" and  "encryption" gets thrown around alot, be sure you understand what they can do for you and what you need. And, if you end up buying a certificate, what you pay for.

There is a rather good layman-explanation of this in Bruce Schneiers [Secrets and lies](http://www.schneier.com/book-sandl.html), and there should be many more places where the concepts are explained.

Answer (score 0):

[SSL & TLS Essentials](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471383546) is a book with a good introduction to SSL. There are also many online [SSL FAQs](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-certificate-faqs.html) that you can start with.